# How to accommodate a FileInputStream object for InputStream object in the constructor call to the class while initializing?

Tags: java, file-io, coldfusion, cfml, default-constructor

### 1 To create and initialize the object for `myDocDesigner`:

Here is the definition of `myDocDesignerclass` with contructor as:

```
public myDocDesigner(customDocFormat doc, InputStream imageStream, int page) throws IOException 
{
    docImageStream(imageStream);
    calculatePageSize(doc, page);
}
```

### 2 From `generateOutputDoc()` in `myFileManager` class as:

```
jMyDocDesigner = createObject("java"
                            ,"myPackage.visible.myDocDesigner")
                            .init(jMyLocalDoc ,myImageFileStream,1);
```

### 3 With attributes defined as:

```
/* load document : `customDocFormat` isn't only a format it also returns the document object of the type `customDocFormat` to be used in #1 & #2 above */

    //document & image file paths
    lStrInputFilePath = "#expandPath('sampledocs')#\mySampleDoc.pdf";
    lStrImageFilePath = "#expandPath('sampledocs')#\myPlacementLogo.png";
    //java FileInputStream object for the PDF file
    lOsPDFInput = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream")
                     .init(CreateObject("java","java.io.File").init(lStrInputPDFfile));
    jMyLocalDoc = createObject("java","myPackage.docModel.customDocFormat");
    jMyLocalDoc.load(lOsPDFInput);
    //FileInputStream Object for image
    lSignImage  = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream")
                      .init(CreateObject("java","java.io.File").init(lStrImageFilePath));
```

### 4 Problem:

To be clear and make things easy: I have tried every possible option to the best of my knowledge of Java. But I cannot get this working. This portion of code is a part of project to manipulate documents based upon some internal requirement and conventions. Every thing is working perfectly...I step debugged the whole code, but this portion is hampering everything....I tried 4-5 variations to convert and pass the `FileInputStream` object to the contructor as `InputStream` but everytime I am getting this error, which is understood, as it is not accepting the parameters I am throwing at it:

[image]

I updated my question, since I found out the cause for the problem lied within the FileInputStream object itself that I initialized as pointed out by [Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) in his answer, comes out I was not going the right way, thanks to him...I was able to move forward with my code and here's the only bug in my code that is stopping the project to be finalized :( :

[image: The <code>PDDocument</code> after loading the original Input document via <code>FileInputStream</code> object has this value of <code>int</code> field <code>UNKNOWN_NUMBER_OF_PAGES</code> as <code>-1</code> every time and to cross-verify that I also called <code>getPageCount()</code> function which returns a value of <code>0</code> irrespective of the no. of pages in my PDF document and no matter how many types of document I use....the surprising thing is that the stream is correctly fetched which might look like the problem in this case...because I was able to construct the duplicate copy using the stream of bytes I read from the stream object. Please help me on this! SOS]

Here are the Java files for PDDocument & PDDocumentInformation classes that I dealing with, and for which I get the incorrect no. of pages after the document is loaded through it: [go here](http://1drv.ms/1Oc5fFK)

Comment: You may refer to this link: http://www.baeldung.com/convert-file-to-input-stream

Comment: I think the problem might be related to parsing. Try to parse the third argument to integer.

Comment: Without more details: what makes you to think the NPE is caused by the InputStream variable? If you have not done so already, start by dumping both variables to confirm they are not null and are both of the correct type. Also, 1) can you post the full stack trace and 2) the constructor of customDocFormat ?

Comment: The dump really does not tell us anything. It shows what looks like a static field. That is just a simple constant.  *this is causing to read the document in a way not intended* Unless it is a public java library (if so, post a URL to the API) we have no way of knowing what your custom class is doing.  You need to post the code for your class, and the full stack trace message.

Comment: In a while [Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) sorry for the short information.

Comment: just updated my question with base java files. To be exact the problem lies within `PDDocument.java` at lines `135`, `710` or `1081`, the first two line no. are the overloaded constructor for the class and the later one being the `load()` method which might be the culprit may be because the document isn't loading properly throuhg it (note: no errors or warning of any kind is thrown here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, works perfectly! The arguments signature for `myDocDesigner`accepts the `FileInputStream` and `OutputStream`objects for the input and output documents. The whole problem was my lacks of java knowledge I admit it but thanks to the group and after some study and testing I made some changes and magically it works. Really happy since I can proceed forward now. Thanks [Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) for your help.

```
        fis = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
        lOsPDFInput = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedInputStream").init(fis.init(arguments.lStrInputPDFfile));
        fos = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream");
        lOsPDFOutput = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedOutputStream").init(fos.init(arguments.lStrOutputPDFfile));
        fimgs = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
        lSignImage = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedInputStream").init(fimgs.init(arguments.lStrSignImageFile));
        fkeys = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
        lKeyStoreFileStream = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedInputStream").init(fkeys.init(arguments.lStrKeyStoreFilePath));
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
lOsPDFInputStream = CreateObject("java","java.io.InputStream");
lOsPDFInputStream = lOsPDFInput;
```

Now try to pass `lOsPDFInput` again since now it's an object of `InputStream`.

You can also try to convert `FileInputStream` to `InputStream`:

```
  public void givenUsingPlainJava_whenConvertingFileToInputStream_thenCorrect() 
  throws IOException {
    File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt");
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
}
```

Ref: http://www.baeldung.com/convert-file-to-input-stream

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: [Pankaj](/users/2039426/pankaj) thanks for the quick reply...but I have already tried your solution but not the second one though.

Comment: `InputStream` is abstract. It cannot be instantiated. Also, `FileInputStream` is a subclass of `InputStream`. No need for casting in CF.

Comment: Thank you [Leigh](/user/104223/leigh), but my question still stands as to why the API has a parameter with `InputStream` object and in that case how do I even pass it to the constructor. I tried the approach by [Pankaj](/user/2039426/pankaj) to assign the `FileInputStream` object directly to the `InputStream` object.....even then the solution isn't  showing any improvement but the same error. Note that the constructor is overloaded in the class, the second type has signature like: (docFileStreamObj,imageFileStreamObj,pageNo), I tried that as well but no luck :(

Comment: I find the solution by [Pankaj](/users/2039426/pankaj) and it was a decent solution to my knowledge and the problem I mentioned...why would you down vote it...please educate me!

Comment: @AnuragMishra The previous code was not correct. I made minor change to the code.

Comment: yes..there was an error but I corrected it while implementing your code.

Comment: (Edit) @AnuragMishra - Originally, the first example didn't even compile. Now it does nothing other than create a new variable. It has zero effect on the FileInputStream. The second example is exactly what you are doing already. Without knowing more, there is no obvious reason why what you posted would not work. As I said [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115943/how-to-accommodate-a-fileinputstream-object-for-inputstream-object-in-the-constr#comment46461572_29115943), you need to post more details.  Starting with the full stack trace.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance [Leigh](/users/104223/leigh), I will update my question with more info shortly. I supassed that error somehow now....but still getting a new error: 
`Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: @AnuragMishra - *the constructor is overloaded in the class* You may need to add a `javacast` to the `int` argument. But there is nothing wrong with how you originally created the first two objects.  As far as the new error, that is not caused by what you posted. Sounds an error thrown by internal code for the classes that we cannot see.

Comment: *try to convert FileInputStream to InputStream*  Seems like you are misunderstanding inheritance.  A FileInputStream IS an InputStream.

Comment: hey [Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) thanks again for giving your time to this post. I actually tried the same thing you suggested here :) and that bug is finally gone now. But I updated my question with the root issue that is the final ladder to this whole project :| Kindly see the update and as always thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: using all sorts of dumps and checks I finally landed on this piece of code in my CFC:
`jMyLocalDoc = createObject("java","myPackage.docModel.customDocFormat");
    jMyLocalDoc.load(lOsPDFInput);`
I guess somehow even though simple enogh to overlook, this is causing to read the document in a way not intended.....Although the stream is perfectly fetched as I already mentioned.